# Help proving $\partial (A \cup B) = \partial A\cup\partial B$?

Tags: real-analysis

```
I know this is a duplicate but the other two haven't helped me much.
```

Fist attempt: Tried proving through double inclusion, but wasn't sure of how to convey being an element of one implied being an element of the other in either direction, although I suspect from left to right would be the easier of the two.

Second attempt: Tried proving equality directly, using the fact that the boundary of a set is equal to the set difference of its closure and interior, but struggled proving closure of union is a union of closures, or the interior of a union is a union of interiors.

I'm getting pretty frustrated and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

It is false.

Consier $\Bbb R$ with usual topology, $A=[0,2]$, $B=[1,3]$.

$$\partial(A\cup B)=\{0,3\}$$
$$\partial A\cup\partial B=\{0,1,2,3\}$$

Just think that some of the border of $A$ can be in the interior of $B$.

Comment: There can also be points in the boundaries of both sets which are not in the boundary of the union. Take $A=[0,1]$ and $B=[1,2]$. Then $1\in\partial A$ and $1\in\partial B$, but $1\notin\partial(A\cup B)$. This typically happens when you "glue" regions together along their boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is fine with respect to the left to right inclusion:
$$ \partial(A\cup B)\subseteq \partial(A)\cup \partial(B) .$$
See a complete formal proof in this MSE [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432109/boundaries-of-finite-intersections-and-unions-of-sets?rq=1).

If $\overline{A} \cap B = \emptyset = A \cap \overline{B}$, then the other inclusion holds too. See a proof in this other MSE [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218805/is-partial-a-cup-b-partial-a-cup-partial-b).