# Boundary of union equal union of boundaries

Tags: general-topology

I would like to show that
$$\tag{*}
\partial ( A \cup B ) = \partial A \cup \partial B
$$
under the condition
$$\tag{**}
\overline{A} \cap B = \varnothing = A \cap \overline{B}
$$

This question has already been asked and correctly answered in, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218805).

> What I'm looking for is a proof in a direct form as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432109), without proving the double inclusion. Is it possible? My attempts gave no positive outcome.

Something like
$$
\begin{align}
\partial ( A \cup B )&=\overline{A\cup B}-(A\cup B)^o\\
&= \overline{A}\cup \overline{B}-(A\cup B)^C{}^C{}^o\\
&= \overline{A}\cup \overline{B}-(A^C\cap B^C){}^C{}^o\\
&= (\overline{A}\cup \overline{B})\cap (A^C\cap B^C){}^C{}^o{}^C\\
&= (\overline{A}\cup \overline{B})\cap \overline{A^C\cap B^C}\\
\end{align}
$$

or starting from the bottom
$$
\begin{align}
\partial A \cup \partial B 
&=(\overline{A}-A^o)\cup(\overline{B}-B^o)\\
&=(\overline{A}\cap A^o{}^C)\cup(\overline{B}\cap B^o{}^C)\\
&=(\overline{A}\cap \overline{A^C})\cup(\overline{B}\cap \overline{B^C})
\end{align}
$$

and somewhere apply (**) to get (*).

Comment: If you provide your attempt it will help me understand what you mean by "a proof in a direct form".

Comment: @Yanko I would like a sequence of equalities; I edited the question

Comment: A proof is a proof. Why does it have to be a chain of equalities? Maybe you're too stuck on set algebra?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma In my option would be a nicer proof. I can do also without it. However the condition (**) is so simple that I imagined that it could be replaced in some expansion of one of the two sides of the equation. If someone find the proof is good, otherwise it is also good.